# Deploying Django on OS 10.9 Server

Tags: python, django, apache, pythonpath, osx-server

I have a project that uses Django that I'm attempting to deploy on a local network on a machine running OS X Server (10.9). I can run it locally with the project's manage.py script and have all of the dependencies and everything, but am struggling to get it running as a regular website through Server.app. Below are the configuration files for the project required by web applications on the server, all pointing to the actual code in :

```
/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/project/.../
```

(it's not actually named project, I promise):

/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_project.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /unity /Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/unity/unity/site.wsgi
```

/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps/com.apple.webapp.project.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>name</key>
<string>com.apple.webapp.project</string>
<key>displayName</key>
<string>Daily Download</string>
<key>launchKeys</key>
<array/>
<key>proxies</key>
<dict/>
<key>installationIndicatorFilePath</key>
<string>/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/project/project/site.wsgi</string>
<key>includeFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_project.conf</string>
</array>
<key>requiredModuleNames</key>
<array>
    <string>wsgi_module</string>
</array>
```

I've already added it as a website in Server.app. The issue is that I'm getting 500 errors with the following entry in /private/var/log/apache2/error_log:

```
[Mon Jan 06 14:55:21 2014] [error] [client 17.19.244.170] ImportError: Could not import  settings 'project.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named unity.settings
```

This is weird to me because I've added that directory to my PYTHONPATH and can import project.settings from the Python prompt. At least it's calling my code, but I can't figure out this system path issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about Server.app, but what user does it run as? You say the directory is in your PYTHONPATH, but presumably the server is not running as you.

Comment: It's running as the administrator account, I manually added to (exported) the PYTHONPATH to my .bash_profile. Now that I think about it, is there another place I would need to specify it so that it will be recognized by Apache instead of a bash session?

Answer (score 2):

I just setup django 1.6.1 with OS 10.9 Server yesterday.

File /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_wsgi2.conf
[..]

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/jens/Source/macmini/macmini/macmini.wsgi

<Directory /Users/jens/Source/macmini>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

[..]

File /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps/com.apple.webapp.wsgi2.plist

[...]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-7"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>com.apple.webapp.wsgi2</string>
        <key>displayName</key>
        <string>Django 1.6.1 Setup at / </string>
        <key>launchKeys</key>
        <array/>
        <key>proxies</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>installationIndicatorFilePath</key>
        <string>/Users/jens/Source/macmini/macmini/macmini.wsgi</string>
        <key>includeFiles</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_wsgi2.conf</string>
        </array>
        <key>requiredModuleNames</key>
        <array>
                <string>wsgi_module</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[...]

Propably noteworthy I installed django within the Home directoty of Jens

[...]

```
macmini:macmini jens$ ls -l
total 72
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff     0 14 Jan 20:43 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff   133 14 Jan 21:10 __init__.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jens  staff   482 15 Jan 09:43 macmini.wsgi
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff  4384 15 Jan 17:15 settings.py
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff  3902 15 Jan 17:16 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff   298 14 Jan 20:43 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff   413 14 Jan 21:53 urls.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jens  staff   466 14 Jan 23:46 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 jens  staff   590 14 Jan 21:52 wsgi.pyc
```

[...]

And finaly the wsgi.py file

[...]

```
"""
WSGI config for macmini project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "macmini.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

[...]

Make sure that you now create a virtual site within the Server.app.

Cheers, Jens